# Is busybox available in shared library form?

Tags: c, linux

Is busybox available in shared library form? I would like to use individual apps programmatically instead of using `system()`. I've heard about libbusybox and libbb but could not find any documentation.

Comment: Don't use system(). execve() and friends are less likely to do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 8):

There exists busybox library in a shared form called `libbusybox(.so)`, you just have to enable it while making menuconfig. When you have compiled, it will be avalible in `0_lib` folder. In this library you have nice little function called `int lbb_main(char **argv)`.

What you need to do in your code is something like this:

```
extern int lbb_main(char **argv);

int main()
{
    char* strarray[] = {"ifconfig",0};
    lbb_main(strarray);

    return 1;
}
```

You could import `libb.h`, but that didn't work for me, because I got many errors.

After that you just have to compile using somethin like `gcc -o code code.c -Lpath_to_0_lib_fodler -lbusybox`and that's it!

To intercept output you will have to redefine printf and similar calls, buts that's clearly doable by using soemthing macros like `#define printf(...) code' in`libb.h'.

You could even spawn busybox's shell that doesn't use fork or system, but that doesn't work well yet.

Comment: If `#include "libb.h"` causes "many errors", there's a serious problem somewhere. It would be good to know more about that. You definitely shouldn't have to redeclare library functions yourself; that's what headers are for.

Comment: it's sad but there is not libbb in Debian repos and it looks like nobody ever used it

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a tiny embedded system where it matters, you can link your own app into the busybox binary, then you can call its functions without any dynamic linker at all.

If you are not, just use system(), or some fork/exec combo.

It is unlikely you'll want to call the utilities so often that performance matters.